# How to perform mysql like sorting in a php array?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

```
$myarray=
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 4
                       [name] => ABC
                       [point] => 2111 
      ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 5
                       [name] => XYZ 
                       [point] => 1305 )




$points = array_map(function($myarray) {
        return $store[0];
    }, $myarray);

 $maxpoint=max($points)
```

But how will I get the `id` of the person with max points? 
Basically I need to get the row (or inner array) where the point is maximum.

How is it possible to perform mysql like sorting in this array with only using `php`?

Please Help

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I sort arrays and data in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)

Comment: @Don'tPanic:  I would agree if they had asked how to sort, though that may be the best way.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I'm not trying to be argumentative, but didn't they? _"How is it possible to perform mysql like sorting in this array with only using php?"_

Comment: @Don'tPanic:  Yes, I guess I could have read the title, sorry :-(

Comment: @AbraCadaver No worries. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine them but here are the general steps:

```
// extract all points and get the max()
$maxpoint = max(array_column($myarray, 'point'));

// get the key of the array with the max points
$key = array_search(array_column($myarray, 'point'), $maxpoint);

// get the id using the key
$id = $myarray[$key]['id'];

// or get the entire array
$result = $myarray[$key];
```

Another option is to sort on `point` descending so that it will always be index 0:

```
array_multisort(array_column($myarray, 'point'), SORT_DESC, $myarray);

echo 'id ' . $myarray[0]['id'] . ' has ' . $myarray[0]['point'] . ' points';
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with the accepted answer, (it's great, actually) but if all you need is the person with the highest score, you don't need to sort the array. You can just iterate it and keep track of the highest pointer as you go.

```
$person['point'] = 0; // starting value

foreach ($myarray as $row) {
    if ($row['point'] > $person['point']) {
        $person = $row; // replace $person with new highest points person
    }
}
```